# 3-Tier application with WPF and C#

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, desktop-application

I have recently read about the 3 tier architecture, and i would like to know how to apply it in developing **Desktop Applications** using WPF and C#.
any reference to external articles or resources is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried googling "3 tier architecture .NET"? There are enough responses there for you to find something useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"3-tier architecture in WPF" instantly makes me answer you "MVVM - Model View View-Model"

[This quick start tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF) can help you getting started with it.

I highly recommend working in MVVM with WPF anyway. I'd even say that, using WPF without working in MVVM does not make a lot of sense imho

You also have a more strict framework named PRISM, google it if you want

Anyway, for MVVM, a lot more anwers are listed in:

[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)